# Can anyone explain this bizarre JS behavior concerning string concatenation?

Tags: javascript, string, scope

I just posted this to a gist: https://gist.github.com/2228570

```
var out = '';

function doWhat(){
    out += '<li>';
    console.log(out === '<li>'); // at this point, out will equal '<li>'
    return '';
}

out += doWhat();
console.log(out, out === '<li>');
// I expect out to == '<li>', but it's actually an empty string!?
```

This behavior is odd, does anyone have an explanation? This is a tough thing to google. It also makes no difference if you use `out +=` or `out = out +`.

EDIT: @paislee made a JSFiddle that demonstrates how if doWhat is on a separate line, it behaves as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/Y4WE8/

Comment: Edited my answer slightly to provide explanation **and** solution that achieves the wanted functionality (adding strings to `out` within the function and adding the return value to `out`). Just needed to switch `out` and `doWhat()` (`out = doWhat() + out` instead of `out = out + doWhat()`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you're expecting `doWhat` to be called before the `+=` is evaluated.

But, the progression of the line is:

```
out += doWhat();      // original line
out = out + doWhat(); // expand `+=`
out = '' + doWhat();  // evaluate `out`, which is currently an empty string
out = '' + '';        // call `doWhat`, which returns another empty string
out = '';             // result
```

The `out += '<li>';` inside `doWhat` is updating the variable, but too late to have a lasting effect.

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution because it most clearly (to me) explains the behavior, thus answering the original question. For solutions, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9913555/169491 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9913382/169491

Answer (score 6):

The confusion is that you expect `doWhat()` to also modify `out` directly. Apparently, the value that you will append to is retrieved before this function is called.

Here's the logic:

1. Get the value of `out` ('')
2. Call `doWhat()` and append the result to the first value ('' + '' = '')
3. Assign the result to `out` ('')

Mixing return values and direct modifications this way is just asking for problems, as aptly demonstrated in your example. Perhaps you should try returning `<li>` instead.

Comment: I think the confusion is that he assigns to `out` inside `doWhat`. (It's not actually the same `out`; the inner `out` shadows the outer one.)

Comment: += not = ... that's totally different.

Comment: @isbadawi interesting but note http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/Y4WE8/ (it doesn't shadow in this case!?)

Comment: @isbadawi he didn't use  `var out` inside `doWhat`, so I don't see any shadowing. Or am I blind ?

Comment: doWhat returns an empty string just to return something. I would expect `out` within the function to reference the `out` that is outside of it. And if you were to separate the function call and the concatenation onto separate lines, this would work as I expect. Yes, `out` within is referencing the outer scope, but this is how JS works.

Comment: @paislee EXACTLY! It's something to do with +=, I believe

Comment: @isbadawi, actually, it *is* the same variable. In javascript, variables are global by default (rather than the reverse). So, unless you specifically put `var` in front of `out` inside the function, it will continue up until it either finds a `var out` or creates a new global called `out`.

Comment: @Andrew, imagine it like this: `var out = '';function doWhat(){out = '<li>';return '';}out = ''+doWhat();` which is the same as `out = ''+'';` (`out += doWhat();` == `out = out + doWhat();` == `out = '' + doWhat;` because the value of `out` is read *before* the function is called.)

Also note that what you mentioned in your first comment can be achieved by simply making a call to `doWhat()` rather than assigning the return of `doWhat()` to `out`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `out` is a bit like a stream that I'm just trying to write to when the function is called, and also, potentially, add whatever the function returns to the stream as well.

Comment: @Andrew, no problem. I put it into an answer with a slightly better (imo) explanation, and some example solutions.

Answer (score 2):

## Imagine it like this:

```
// out is undefined
var out = '';
// out is ''
function doWhat(){
 out += '<li>';
 // out is '<li>';
 return '';
}
out = out + doWhat();
// out += doWhat(); is the same as:
// out = out + doWhat(); is the same as :
// out = '' + doWhat; because the value of `out` is read when `out` is first found
// out is ''
```

And linearized:

```
// out is undefined
var out = '';
// out is ''
out += '<li>';
// out is '<li>';
out = '' + ''; // first '' is value of `out` before function is called, second is what the function returns
// out is ''
```

## Solution

```
var out = '';
function doWhat(){
 out += '<li>';
 return '';
}
out = doWhat() + out; // Note `out` is *after* `doWhat()`
```

## TL;DR

Currently, your code evaluates the same as:

```
out = out + doWhat();
```

This reads the value of `out` *before* `doWhat()` is called. To get it working how you expect it to, simply reverse the order:

```
out = doWhat() + out;
```

This will read the value of `out` *after* `doWhat()` as you expect.

Comment: Wow, I never would have thought of that for the solution! Definitely simpler than what I was going to do...

Comment: @Andrew, glad it works for ya :) Could you accept this answer to mark the question resolved? (See [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) in the FAQ.)

Comment: I will mark one of these as answered, both you and @cmw provided good solutions.

Comment: @Andrew, I added a simplified explanation to the end that explains the comment from the solution in greater detail :)

Answer (score 1):

As Jonathan said above, you're returning an empty string from the function, so even though you're modifying a global variable by appending `'<li>'` to `out` inside of `doWhat`, javascript is going to append the returned value from the function to the value of `out` when you made the function call.

You can also just do:

```
var out = '';

function doWhat(){
    out += '<li>';
    return true;
}

doWhat();
```

Is there any particular reason you need to add things to the string both inside the function and after its value is returned?

[edit]

Looking at the actual example you posted in the comments to this answer, it appears to me you might be trying to conditionally return an additional value to append to `out` from `doWhat`. Correct me if I'm wrong. Your code looks like this:

```
var out = '', temp;

function doWhat(){
   out += '<li>';
}

out += typeof (temp = doWhat()) === 'undefined' ? '' : temp;
```

From this presentation, the value of temp will always be undefined because the function returns nothing that can be typed. If you are planning on having the function sometimes return a value that you then append, you can achieve what you're looking for by breaking it into two lines at the end:

```
var out = '', temp;
function doWhat(){
    out += '<li>';
}
temp = doWhat();
out += typeof (temp === undefined) ? '' : temp;
```

This is a little bit awkward, though, and I would probably try to move both appends inside the function.

```
var out = '';
function doWhat () {
   out += '<li>';
   if (some condition is met) { out += 'some extra string'; }
}
doWhat();
```

Comment: I only added the return value to simplify the example. The real example: https://gist.github.com/2228570/48977b42d11ec7fd06e8cff7f3375e47a03ca4d8 The reason for all of this is for a templating library named Vash: http://github.com/kirbysayshi/vash

Comment: Why are you evaluating the `typeof` your function call? If it has no return value it will always be undefined. Does your real function have a conditional return value?

Comment: it's because the function call, in this situation, could return a value, or not. If it returns a value, that should be added to `out`, because the whole thing is a bit like a response stream. The typeof is to see if the function returns anything, and if not, replace it's output with an empty string to keep the whole concatenation valid.

Comment: @cmw: You mention "closure". I don't think this is a closure. (Am I wrong?) It's simply a function that references a global variable and the output that the OP is getting is a result of the order of execution.

Comment: Andrew, that's what I suspected. I've updated my answer accordingly. @w3d, you're right, my mistake. Corrected the terminology of my answer.

Comment: Your update answer is awesome, your solution of a temporary variable is actually what I was decided to go with before posting this question!